# python) can you translate this code? (for, for, if statement, COCI 2012/2013)

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

This is dial task from COCI 2012/2013 6th round:https://hsin.hr/coci/archive/2012_2013/contest6_tasks.pdf page 2

```
dial = {"ABC":3, "DEF":4, "GHI":5, "JKL":6, "MNO":7, "PQRS":8, "TUV":9, "WXYZ":10}
phN = input()
time = 0

for i in range(len(phN)):
    for v in (dial.get(key) for key in dial.keys() if phN[i] in key):  
        time += v

print(time)
```

I tried with dictionary, so I wanted to find how to match dictionary but part of them.
I googled and found answer:

```
for v in (dial.get(key) for key in dial.keys() if phN[i] in key):
```

Why is **dial.get(key)** staying in front of for **key** ~ statement?
Why is **if** statement behind of **for** statement?
What's this type of statement's name?(How can I google this?)

Answer (score 0):

You are using list compreenssion [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) and [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
The get function is to access a value from a dict, but you can pass a default value if the key doesn't exist:

```
a = {'k':'value'}

a['k'] # 'value'
a['f'] # Raise Exception

a.get('k') # 'value'
a.get('f','default') # 'default'
```

Just the syntax equal as below

```py
for key in dial:
  if phN[i] in key:
     for v in dial.get(key):
       print(v)
```